# Capacitor ID & Where to Purchase

Tags: capacitor

My electric fence zap box surrounding my bee yard stopped working. When I took the box apart I noticed a burnt spot on this capacitor.  The only numbers I can see on this part is E 103M AKV. What does this label mean? Thanks for the help in advance.

[image]

Comment: That does not say AKV, it says **8kV**. It's a high voltage 10000pF ceramic capacitor.

Comment: Thank you for your help and I apologize it does say 8kv.

Comment: DigiKey:  5550B103K802LE-ND

Answer (score 3):

It's a 10nF "8kV" ceramic capacitor. It probably won't be easy to find from a reliable supplier. You can use a higher voltage rated part.

I see some on eBay that are marked 10nF (103M) 20kV, but if you believe that I have a nice bridge in Dongguan you might be interested in.

Answer (score 2):

This is a high voltage 8kV, not AKV, ceramic capacitor that has a capacitance of 10nF. You can find this capacitor anywhere on the internet.

The 103M means, 10 followed by three zeros. Hence 10,000pF or 10nF. The "M" indicates its tolerance of \$ \pm \$20%. I think that "E" on the top there represents a "Max Capacitance Change Over Temperature Rating". If I'm correct, then it the rating is a \$ \pm \$4.7%.

I don't think I'm allowed to recommend where you can get it since that is probably against the rules on this website but you can find it multiple places on the internet like Amazon or eBay, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your help...  Can you please tell me which number off the part I would use if I were to search on Amazon or eBay?

Comment: Oh just search for 8kV, 103M capacitor on Google and you'll see a lot of results where you can buy it from.

Comment: Thanks once again...I apologize to this forum if I placed my question in the wrong category or went about asking for help the wrong way.  Hope everyone has a great day !!!

Comment: You're welcome! Let me know if you need anymore help! :) Yeah just make sure you read some guidelines on how to ask questions on this website: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help